# Bootstrap offcanvas slide right to left

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-transitions

On click of "Hamburger", slide the off canvas from right to left. If click on outside off canvas should close. I have till here. Please help out.

> The [JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mohanacchu/5af1m4tv/3/)

```css
.nav-side-menu {
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #2e353d;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #e1ffff;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.nav-side-menu .brand {
  background-color: #23282e;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
  display: none;
}
.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*    
    .collapsed{
       .arrow:before{
                 font-family: FontAwesome;
                 content: "\f053";
                 display: inline-block;
                 padding-left:10px;
                 padding-right: 10px;
                 vertical-align: middle;
                 float:right;
            }
     }
*/
}
.nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f078";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
  background-color: #181c20;
  border: none;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #020203;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-side-menu li {
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
}
.nav-side-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu li a i {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.nav-side-menu li:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu {
      top:0;
      right:0;
    
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
   
  }
  /*.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {*/
  /*  display: block;*/
  /*  cursor: pointer;*/
  /*  position: absolute;*/
  /*  right: 10px;*/
  /*  top: 10px;*/
  /*  z-index: 10 !important;*/
  /*  padding: 3px;*/
  /*  background-color: #ffffff;*/
  /*  color: #000;*/
  /*  width: 40px;*/
  /*  text-align: center;*/
  /*}*/
  .brand {
      display:none !important;

  }
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
    display: block;
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!---->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse bg-light navbar-fixed-top navbar-color ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home LOGO</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Trouble Logging in ?</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/action_page.php">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="Search" style="border-right: 0px;">
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default search-icon" type="submit">
                              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                </form>
                
              
          </div> 
               
             
        </div>
      </nav>






<!---->







<div class="nav-side-menu">
     <div class="brand">Content</div>
   
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
  
        <div class="menu-list">
  
            <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Dashboard
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> UI Elements <span class="arrow"></span></a>
                </li>
                <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">CSS3 Animation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tabs & Accordions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FontAwesome</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Slider</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Panels</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Model</a></li>
                </ul>


                <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#service" class="collapsed">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i> Services <span class="arrow"></span></a>
                </li>  
                <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="service">
                  <li>New Service 1</li>
                  <li>New Service 2</li>
                  <li>New Service 3</li>
                </ul>


                <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#new" class="collapsed">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car fa-lg"></i> New <span class="arrow"></span></a>
                </li>
                <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="new">
                  <li>New New 1</li>
                  <li>New New 2</li>
                  <li>New New 3</li>
                </ul>


                 <li>
                  <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Profile
                  </a>
                  </li>

                 <li>
                  <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> Users
                  </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

> The transition from right to left.
>   The transition from right to left and on click outside off canvas menu should close.
>   I'm getting unwanted background dark color at the beginning itself.